# How could I integrate bitcoin transfer between users in my mobile/web application?

Tags: exchanges

Hello I wanted to allows users of the application to be able to exchange bitcoin and maybe other cryptocurrencies in the app. I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement this. Can anyone recommend a good method, api, or example I can use to implement this system?

Comment: What kind of exchange do you want? "On-chain" exchange with blockchain transactions or "off-chain" exchange like an exchange market?

Comment: I think on-chain. It would be used for users to tip other users or donate bitcoin. Mostly curious what standard procedure is for this kinda thing and what the best way to implement it is...